# KafkaConsumer loses some alarms which are in others environments

Tags: apache-kafka

I have facing and issue related whit a KafkaConsumer, our scenario is the following we have 5 environments which have a KafkaConsumer implemented, all of them pointing to the same Kafka server and topic also all the consumers have the same config and group.id.

I notice that some of the environments are losing messages but these lose messages are reach other environments. I think that somehow is related with I am using the same group.id.

For example if the message 'A' is present in env1, is not present in env2,3,4,5.

Could someone give me an idea of what could be the cause or if is related with the group.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, learn in details what is really a Consumer Group. In few words: it means that one instance in the group is going to consume from a subset of topic-partitions at a time. All other instances may consume from the same topic, but only will read from different partitions - partitions do not overlap.

So, since you say that some of your messages don't reach some specific consumer but do reach others, that means these messages are routed to different partitions.

Not sure what is your business goal, but here is a detailed Apache Kafka docs about Consumer Groups: https://dev.to/de_maric/what-is-a-consumer-group-in-kafka-49il